# iOS 9 and universal links on Safari from an iframe

Tags: ios, iframe, ios9, ios-universal-links

I am trying to get a universal link to my `iOS` app working on `iOS 9`.
The link should be displayed in an iframe.

As of now I have got it working correctly for chrome on `iOS 9` using:

```
<a href="https://demo.linkid.be/purpose?code=linkiddemo%3A%2F%2Fscan" target="_blank">Chrome iOS 9 all good</a>
```

This link does not work on Safari from an iframe tho.
Through some experimenting I found that following link does work when called from my local ip:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('https://demo.linkid.be/purpose?code=linkiddemo%3A%2F%2Fscan')">Safari iOS 9 problem case</a>
```

But for some reason this will not open my iOS app when I add this link on a page hosted at the same domain as the universal link (demo.linkid.be)

Any thoughts? Or is this a bug in Safari at this time?

[Update]

Safari iOS 9 with following link will work if you long press the link.
An action sheet appears allowing you to open it via the app.

```
<a href="https://demo.linkid.be/purpose?code=linkiddemo%3A%2F%2Fscan" target="_blank">Chrome iOS 9 all good</a>
```

Comment: I am also facing same problem cant able to click inside an iframe, do you get any solution for this issue?

Comment: No solution found for this issue. We have worked around this one by eliminating the need for an iframe so I am not actively searching for a solution anymore. If I stumble upon one off course I will update

Comment: @WimV Did you get any solution for this ? I am facing the same problem

Comment: Sorry no update on this one. As said, we got rid of the need for an iframe as it just added an unnecessary complexity, so have not actively searched for a workaround/fix

Answer (score 0):

In order to make a universal link inside of an iframe work in Safari on iOS9 you can use `target="_top"`. The tradeoff is that the link will open in the same window.